# Why is Pandas not finding my specified columns in a CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, keyword

everyone.

This my Python code. I would like to do a alpha Cronbach's test on a csv datafile.

```
import pandas as pd
import pingouin as pg

# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\data analysis\\Classeur2.csv", header=0) 

# Print the column names to verify they are correct
print("Column names:", data.columns)

# Check if the specified columns exist in the DataFrame
selected_columns = ["doubt_A", "doubt_B", ";doubt_C", "doubt_D", "doubt_E"]
missing_columns = [col for col in selected_columns if col not in data.columns]

if missing_columns:
    print("Error: Columns not found in the DataFrame:", missing_columns)
else:
    # Select the columns for the scale questions
    data_columns = data[selected_columns]

    # Calculate Cronbach's alpha
    alpha_score = pg.cronbach_alpha(data=data_columns)

    print("Cronbach's alpha score:", alpha_score)
```

What is very strange is that this is the output message :

```
\*Column names: Index(\['BAC', 'ETUDE', 'NFC_A', 'NFC_B', 'NFC_C', 'NFC_D', 'NFC_E',
'NFC_F;NFC_G;NFC_H;NFC_I;NFC_J;STAI1;STAI2;STAI3;STAI4;STAI5;age;conflit;doubt_A;doubt_B;doubt_C;doubt_D;doubt_E;doute_glo;responses'\],
dtype='object')
Error: Columns not found in the DataFrame: \['doubt_A', 'doubt_B', ';doubt_C', 'doubt_D', 'doubt_E'\]
```

It gives me the names of the columns. There is doubt_A, doubt_B and so on. But it also considers those columns not found in my csv file.*

I really don't get it.

Thank you for the time spend reading this.

I tried to change the column name, but it didn't work.

Comment: What is the output of data.columns?

Comment: Show us the first few lines of the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe contains the column `'NFC_F;NFC_G;NFC_H;NFC_I;NFC_J;STAI1;STAI2;STAI3;STAI4;STAI5;age;conflit;doubt_A;doubt_B;doubt_C;doubt_D;doubt_E;doute_glo;responses'`. **Note that this is a single column.**. When you check if e.g. 'doubt_D' is in your dataframe, it wont match. It is very likely that Pandas cannot read your csv correctly.